# How to add a new datetime column to a spark dataFrame from existing timestamp column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in Spark that has a column timestamp. I want to add a new column to this data frame that has the DateTime in the below format created from this existing timestamp column.

“YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS”

Comment: See documentation `df = spark.createDataFrame([('1997-02-28 10:30:00',)], ['t'])
df.select(to_date(df.t, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('date'))` https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise [to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) -

```
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext
>>> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> 
>>> sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
>>> sql = SQLContext(sc)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> input_list = [
...   (1,"2019-11-07 10:30:00")
...   ,(1,"2019-11-08 10:30:00")
...   ,(1,"2019-11-09 10:30:00")
...   ,(1,"2019-11-11 10:30:00")
...   ,(1,"2019-11-12 10:30:00")
...   ,(1,"2019-11-13 10:30:00")
...   ,(1,"2019-11-14 10:30:00")
...   ,(2,"2019-11-08 10:30:00")
...   ,(2,"2019-11-09 10:30:00")
...   ,(3,"2019-11-09 10:30:00")
...   ,(3,"2019-11-10 10:30:00")
...   ,(3,"2019-11-11 10:30:00")
...   ,(2,"2019-11-15 10:30:00")
...   ,(2,"2019-11-18 10:30:00")
...   ,(4,"2019-11-10 10:30:00")
...   ,(4,"2019-11-11 10:30:00")
... ]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['customerid','date'])
>>> 
>>> sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('date_timestamp',F.to_timestamp(F.col('date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
>>> sparkDF.show()
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|customerid|               date|     date_timestamp|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|         1|2019-11-07 10:30:00|2019-11-07 10:30:00|
|         1|2019-11-08 10:30:00|2019-11-08 10:30:00|
|         1|2019-11-09 10:30:00|2019-11-09 10:30:00|
|         1|2019-11-11 10:30:00|2019-11-11 10:30:00|
|         1|2019-11-12 10:30:00|2019-11-12 10:30:00|
|         1|2019-11-13 10:30:00|2019-11-13 10:30:00|
|         1|2019-11-14 10:30:00|2019-11-14 10:30:00|
|         2|2019-11-08 10:30:00|2019-11-08 10:30:00|
|         2|2019-11-09 10:30:00|2019-11-09 10:30:00|
|         3|2019-11-09 10:30:00|2019-11-09 10:30:00|
|         3|2019-11-10 10:30:00|2019-11-10 10:30:00|
|         3|2019-11-11 10:30:00|2019-11-11 10:30:00|
|         2|2019-11-15 10:30:00|2019-11-15 10:30:00|
|         2|2019-11-18 10:30:00|2019-11-18 10:30:00|
|         4|2019-11-10 10:30:00|2019-11-10 10:30:00|
|         4|2019-11-11 10:30:00|2019-11-11 10:30:00|
+----------+-------------------+-------------------+

>>>
```